# javascript in acrobat- word limit in text fields

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I am currently setting up a questionnaire with different text fields. I am hoping to add the js to different text fields as to limit the number of words they will type. What will be the js code for On Focus tab? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of a word, exactly? Do you want to limit the number of word in an individual field or the total number of words in multiple fields?

Comment: Words are separated with a space whereas PDF only allows us to limit the number of characters in a field. I was trying to set their answers to be 50 words in maximum (for the first question and 100 words in the others)